# Homfly polynomial for the Hopf Link

Tags: general-topology, polynomials, knot-theory

I am trying to calculate the HOMFLY polynomial for the oriented Hopf link.

I have a left handed corkscrew with linking number $= -1$ (see drawing below).

Using the equation 
$$lP_{H^{+}} + l^{-1}P_{H^{-}} + mP_{H_{0}} = 0$$

I understand what the diagrams of the positive and negative crossings will look like, and that $P_{H_{0}}$ will equal $P_o(\text{the unknot})$ and that $P(\text{unknot})= 1$ but I'm not sure how to turn my equation using diagrams into an equation of two variables.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, it looks like there's a typo in the question, and that the second $l$ should have been an $l^{-1}$.

Now, we claim that the HOMFLY polynomial of a two-component unlink is $-(l+l^{-1})/m$. To see this, add a crossing connecting the two components. Then, no matter if the crossing is positive or negative, the result is an unknot, so it follows from the skein relation that

$$lP(\text{Unknot}) + l^{-1}P(\text{Unknot}) + m P(\text{Two-component unlink}) = 0,$$

from which the claim follows. That is, in pictures,

[image: Skein relation for calculating the HOMFLY polynomial of a two-component unlink]

Moving on to the Hopf link, let's focus on the topmost (negative) crossing.

- Resolving that one into a positive crossing will leave you with a two-component unlink.
- Resolving it into a non-crossing leaves you with an unknot.

Now, by the skein relation

$$l P(\text{Two-component unlink}) + l^{-1}P(\text{Hopf link}) + mP(\text{Unknot}) = 0$$

or, once again in pictures,

[image: Skein relation of the Hopf link]

Rearranging things a bit, we find that

$$P(\text{Hopf link}) = -l(l P(\text{Two-component unlink}) + mP(\text{Unknot})) = -l(l(-(l+l^{-1})/m) + m) = l^3m^{-1} + lm^{-1} -lm.$$